# Why my Socketio server is not working with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to implement sockets in my Express server, and my code looks like this:
App class:

```
app: Application;
server: http.Server | https.Server;
sockets: SocketIo;

constructor() {
   this.app = express();
   this.app.use(cors());
   this.server = http.createServer(this.app);
   this.iniciarSockets();
   this.server.listen(3000, () => .....)
}

private async iniciarSockets() {
 this.sockets = new SocketIo(this.server);
}
```

My SocketIo class looks like this:

```
import http from 'http';
import https from 'https';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';
export class SocketIo {
  io: Server;

  constructor(server: http.Server | https.Server) {
      this.io = require("socket.io")(server);

       this.io.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
          console.log("New connection");
          socket.emit("test event", "Here is some data");
        
      })
}
}
```

But when I try to access it from Angular using a service, I get the following three errors in the console:
zone.js:2707 GET http://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OXzMsOL 404 (Not Found)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OXzMsOR' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OXzMsOR net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

My Angular service looks like this, I followed a video on Youtube:

```
export class WebSocketService {

  socket: any;
  readonly url: string = "ws://localhost:3000";

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
   }

  listen(eventName: string) {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      this.socket.on(eventName, (data) => {
        subscriber.next(data);
      })
    })
  }

  emit(eventName: string, data: any) {
    this.socket.emit(eventName, data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please state the version of your front-end and back-end socket-io dependencies as there are strict rules about the compatibility of these versions.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a CORs permission issue in trying to access port 3000 from a web page served by port 4200.  This is a typical issue with the two server model (each on a different port) used by angular.

This error message appears to be key:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OXzMsOR' 
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

You have a couple options.  If your socket.io client specifies that the transport is webSocket, then socket.io will not start the connection process with a series of plain http requests and thus will not be subject to CORs restrictions.

You can do this by changing this client code:

```
this.socket = io(this.url);
```

to this:

```
this.socket = io(this.url, { transports: ['websocket'] });
```

This will tell socket.io to go directly to the webSocket transport and will thus not be subject to CORs restrictions.

Or, you can add the proper code to the web server that your socket.io server is hooked to to allow CORs requests.

---

FYI, I always  use `http:` URLs with socket.io, not `ws:` so I'd also suggest you change this:

```
readonly url: string = "ws://localhost:3000";
```

to this:

```
readonly url: string = "http://localhost:3000";
```

Perhaps `ws` URLs work (I don't actually know), but it's really an http request that establishes the initial socket.io transport so that seems like what you should be using.

Comment: Ok, thank you @jfriend00. I will try all those things
Although I tried adding a CORS configuration object to the socket and it worked, I will try these things you mentioned to see if I can develop it in a better way.
And as you said, I have already deleted the previous post. Thank you very much for your help!